# Datatable autorefresh in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have this table in my view as you can see :

```
<table id="DataTable" class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th >نام و نام خانوادگی </th>
            <th></th>
            <th>وقت ملاقات </th>
            <th>ملاقات شونده </th>
            <th>زمان ورود </th>
            <th>زمان خروج </th>
            <th>عملیات</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (ReferralTrafficView item in Model)
    {
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my datatable config:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DataTable').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "pageLength": 10,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "همه"]],
            "ordering": true,
            "processing": true,
            "info": true,
            "dom": "<'row'<'col-md-6 text-right'f><'col-md-6 text-left'>>"
            + "<'row'<'col-md-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-md-5 text-right rtl'p> <'col-md-7 text-left'i>>",
            "language": {
                "search": "_INPUT_",
                "searchPlaceholder": "جستجو...", "sLoadingRecords": "در حال دریافت اطلاعات...", "sProcessing": "در حال پردازش...",
                "lengthMenu": "نمایش _MENU_ ردیف در هر صفحه",
                "zeroRecords": "موردی یافت نشد!",
                "info": "نمایش صفحه _PAGE_ از _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "داده قابل نمایش موجود نیست.",
                "infoFiltered": "(_TOTAL_ مورد از کل _MAX_ یافت شد)",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
                    "sPrevious": "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
                }
            }

        });
    });

</script>
```

My data in the Model is changed every times,i want to refresh my datatable without refresh .here is my controller :

```
 public ActionResult MyReception(string Id)
        {

            List<ReferralTrafficView> rf = new List<ReferralTrafficView>();
get data from database
return rf
}
```

Can i set the controller in datatable configuration to get data automatically and refresh data without reload the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your DataTable gather its data from an ajax source. DataTables allows you to configure the URL of the server side endpoint that will retrieve the table content.
Then add a button that onclick calls the function table.ajax.reload(). Also you might want to use setInterval() to automatically call this function periodically.

Check the documentation on setting your [ajax source](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax), and the [ajax reload function](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()).

Another option is to update the data portion of the table and fire a redraw of the grid.
https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()